# Getting segmentation fault with c++ pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

So I'm trying to familiarise myself with c++ pointers by running the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int* x;
    cout << &x << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

which works fine and prints the pointer value of x but

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int* x;
    *x = 100;
    cout << &x << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

gives me a segmentation fault when I try to tun it. Why is this? I don't see how that extra line should change anything about the address of x.

Comment: Of course it does... `x` is an uninitialized pointer. Writing to it is therefore undefined behavior. You have to initialize the pointer first, either by allocating memory like `x = new int;` or pointing it at an existing variable like `x = &someExistingInt;`. (Note that when you `cout << &x` you're printing the address of the pointer, i.e. the address of the local variable `x`, not the *value* of the pointer or the address it points to.)

Comment: `*x = 100;` because you didn't initialize the pointer to point at a valid memory location where your value can be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and prints the pointer value of x but

Not exactly.

- `std::cout << &x;` it prints `x`'s address (the pointer's address);
- `std::cout << x;` prints the address, `x` points to;
- `std::cout << *x;` prints what `x` points to;

---

```
int* x;
*x = 100;
```

Here, `x` is just a pointer, you need to allocate memory for the `100`. For example

```
int* x = new int;
*x = 100;
std::cout << *x;
```

Or just

```
int* x = new int( 100 );
std::cout << *x;
```

Without allocating memory and leaving `x` uninitialized, by `*x = 100` you're trying to change some random memory, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

You did not allocate an object which you are going to assign.

```
int* x;
```

The value of x is unspecified and can be any arbitrary value. So the next statement

```
*x = 100;
```

is invalid.

You have to write

```
x = new int;

*x = 100;
```

Or

```
x = new int( 100 );
```

Or even

```
x = new int { 100 };
```

provided that your compiler supports the list initialization for operator new which was introduced in the C++ 2011..

Answer (score 2):

You have *undefined behaviour*.

Your first example is fine since `&x` (which has type `int**`) is the address of a stack allocated pointer. One of the `<<` overloads in `cout` is defined to output that correctly.

In the second example, you are *dereferencing* a pointer that is not pointing to anything. That's *undefined behaviour*; hence the crash. If you'd written

```
int y;
int* x;
x = &y;
*x = 100; /*this means that y is now 100*/
```

then all would have been well since now `x` is pointing to something.